# $(this) vs $('this') in jquery

Tags: jquery

What's the difference between $(this) vs $('this') in jquery ?

Comment: There is no `$('this')` unless you have `<this>`

Comment: The difference is one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: I'd be interested to see anything with `$('this')` that works or is the "some works some doesn't" congruent with the use of `$(this)` vs `$('this')`?

Comment: I'm guessing that the *some that work* are the `$(this)` ones, and the inverse is true for `$('this')`.

Comment: @Richard Neil Ilagan : You are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$(this)**

Here is the current context enclosed in a jQuery Object .

**$('this')**  -- Here this is just a string..

```
$('#btn').on('click', function() {

     $(this).attr('id');

     // Here $(this) is the current current button context that was clicked with i**d btn**
});
```

So $(this) always gets the current context object that was in question..

By default **this** in context is the native DOM element...

Comment: And this in context is the native Dom element

Answer (score 7):

`$('this')` doesn't mean anything useful.

`$('somestring')` returns an element based on a selector 'somestring'.

Here's [the syntax of jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: Unless you have a tag called `<this>`

Comment: @mplungjan That's why I added "useful". I doubt this is the case for OP or he has a very funny colleague.

Comment: Well 'useful' can mean a lot :P

Answer (score 1):

$('this') isn't used... the only thing that would work is $("#this") for a **id** or $(".this") for a **class**

EDIT: or $('this') but that is only used if you have an  tag (stated below)

Comment: Note that a guy in my team who would have used "this" as id or class would get a few words in private.

Comment: Or $('this') for a tag <this>